# How to access service running docker with network_mode: "host" from external IP

Tags: docker, docker-compose, port

**My scenario:**

I have a server with IP x.x.x.x, on which I run a MongoDB instance. I also build my service with a `docker-compose.yml` file as below

```
version: "3" 
services:  
   myApp:
    image: myApplication
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI: mongodb://localhost:27017/myAppDb
```

When I run `docker-compose up` to start the container, I can access my service from my computer via x.x.x.x:8080

But the problem is that my service cannot connect to the mongoDB at localhost:27017, because they're not on the same network. Therefore, I add the option `network_mode: "host"` to my docker-compose file. It solves the problem, my service can connect to the mongoDB running on my server. However, I cannot access my service via x.x.x.x:8080 anymore

**My question:**

How can I still connect to my service via x.x.x.x:80 with the option `network_mode: "host"`? Or is there any way that I don't need to use that option, but my service can still connect to the mongoDB instance?

**Note:** The MongoDB instance is installed in traditional way (yum install mongodb-org) and set up in a way that it can only be accessed via localhost:27017 (or 127.0.0.1:27107). I don't know why or how but that's the way it is, so I cannot change the connection string to mongodb://x.x.x.x:27017. It just won't work.

I also know that I can add mongodb as a service in the `docker-compose` file to achieve my goal, but I don't want to do that since in my case, it's better to manage database separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the only way out is to run the `myApp` container in `host` mode. In this mode the service should be reachable at the IP address of the host on port `8080`. 
If it's not, that's most probably because of firewalling issues.

The same service can be accessed in `bridge` network mode, as in this mode, docker manipulates `iptables` rules to provide access to containers. More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/).

In your specific case docker adds a NAT rule to forward incoming traffic at port `8080` on the host to port `8080` on the container. Executing `iptables`

```
iptables -t nat -L
```

should output the rule:

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:http-alt
...
Chain DOCKER (2 references)
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt to:172.17.0.2:8080
```

where `172.17.0.2` is the `IP` of the container.

The problem is in `host` mode where the publish ports are discarded and docker doesn't add any rule to allow the incoming traffic through port `8080`. You have to add the rule yourself.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I think my case is exactly as what you said. Now that I know a little more about Docker network, I feel stupid to have asked such a dumb question :D

Comment: There is no such thing as a dumb question. Once you understand something you thinks it's obvious.

Comment: help me please, I am using macos and don't there is "iptables"command, you would have other equivalent command ?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced something similar, but i didn't use docker-compose, but i think you might be able to apply the same method.

In stead of using host, you will create your own bridge network(https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/), and then i think your service should be able to access the mongodb, and you should be able to access the mongodb too :)